# Сохранение значения GUID

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
На первый взгляд может вопрос и глупый, но не могу понять, почему пропускает пропускает первое условие и возвращает пустое значение переменной reading? Как решить этот вопрос? Вот код:

```
   public static class CreateGuid
    {
        private static string reading;
        public static string _createGuid()
        {
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string guis = Convert.ToString(guid);

            if (File.Exists(@"С:\75g3cfl098ivc55dxs.txt"))
            {
                //чтение guid'a из файла
                var fs2 = new FileStream(@"C:\75g3cfl098ivc55dxs.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
                var sr = new StreamReader(fs2, Encoding.UTF8);
                while (sr.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    reading = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                sr.Close();
                fs2.Close();
                fs2.Dispose();
            } 
            else
            {
                //Запись guid'a в файл
                var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\75g3cfl098ivc55dxs.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.WriteLine(guis);
                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
            }
            return reading;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Стоит ли в настройках Windows "отображать скрытые и системные файлы"? От этого может зависеть результат выполнения File.Exists

Comment: Думаю в моем случае это роли не играет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Маленький пример:

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string guis = Convert.ToString(guid);
Guid guid2 =  new Guid(guis);
```

В guid2 то же самое теперь находится, что и в guid. А строку можно сохранить куда угодно =)

Comment: Вы имели ввиду эту строку string guis = Convert.ToString(guid) можно сохранить куда угодно?

Comment: Вообще-то, если уж на то пошло, GUID конвертируется в битовый массив и обратно.

Comment: Ну да, куда угодно .з. Хоть в реестр, хоть в файл, хоть в бд, хоть куда ещё - было бы желание. При повторном запуске приложения прочитать и получить guid.

Comment: Реализовал предложенный подход, но он постоянно меняет значение в текстовом файле откуда я его читаю. Как устранить данную проблему?

Comment: Ну так ещё бы? Он при вызове создания гуида ничего не проверяет, создаёт новый, записывает, потом считывает и это возвращает =)
А надо сначала проверить наличие файла. Потом его прочитать. Сделать на основе прочитанного гуид. Если получилось - вернуть. Нет - создаём новый и создаём файл, в который это и запишем.

Comment: >"почему он возвращает значение переменной reading null" - так видно же, что reading инициализируется только при наличии файла. При первом запуске reading так и остаётся пустым...

Answer (score 2):

Если под "повторным запуском формы" понимается перезапуск всего приложения, то сделать нужно так. Необходимо иметь в наличии некоторое заранее определённое внешнее хранилище - либо в файловой системе, либо в реестре. Каждый раз, когда запускается форма, происходит обращение к этому хранилищу.

Если там пусто (нет запрошенного файла либо нет значения в реестре по указанному пути), то генерируется новый Guid и записывается в это хранилище, а также в локальную переменную. Иначе, Guid просто читается из хранилища и тоже записывается в локальную переменную.

Если при перезапуске формы приложение не пересоздаётся, достаточно просто статической переменной, в котрую записывается Guid.

```
public static Guid MyGuid = Guid.Empty;

...

if (MyGuid == Guid.Empty)
  MyGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\" + MyGuid + ".2wvh");...
```

Answer (score 2):

> Реализовал предложенный подход, но он постоянно меняет значение в текстовом файле, откуда я его записываю. Как устранить данную проблему? Код выложил выше.

вместо этого

```
var fs = new @"C:\75g3cfl098ivc55dxs.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```

попробуйте

```
new FileStream(@"C:\75g3cfl098ivc55dxs.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```